# How do I use a Structure in multiple classes?

Tags: vb.net, struct, asp.net-3.5

I want to use this Structure in multiple .vb files within my project:

```
Structure MyStruct
    Dim Name As String
    Dim Good As Boolean 
End Structure
```

If I define it in one file, the other files can't use it. How do I define it globally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make this Structure Public

```
Public Structure MyStruct     
    Dim Name As String     
    Dim Good As Boolean  
End Structure
```

and add this Structure in a Module File so that it can be accessed from anywhere, but give the Module name as a namespace in your class

```
using Module1.vb
```